# Tomcat cannot find servlet

Tags: tomcat, servlets, gwt, deployment, http-status-code-404

I'm currently working on a GWT program deployed to Tomcat 7, and my program isn't responding on the button click.

After digging through the logs a bit, I seem to have found the problem. In my access logs, I found this:

```
[31/Mar/2016:02:27:19 +0000] "GET /test6/ HTTP/1.1" 404 963
[31/Mar/2016:02:27:38 +0000] "POST /LuceneServlet HTTP/1.1" 404 977
[31/Mar/2016:02:27:39 +0000] "POST /LuceneServlet HTTP/1.1" 404 977
[31/Mar/2016:02:27:40 +0000] "POST /LuceneServlet HTTP/1.1" 404 977
[31/Mar/2016:02:27:41 +0000] "POST /LuceneServlet HTTP/1.1" 404 977
```

so it looks like the servlet was never found. The war file was created by eclipse and GWT compiler. This is the web.xml that was created.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>PerformSearchImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.utm.csc.server.PerformSearchImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PerformSearchImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SearchTest/PerformSearch</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/LuceneServlet</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 <!-- Servlets -->

  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>LuceneServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
    com.utm.csc.server.LuceneServlet
  </servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>LuceneServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/LuceneServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

What is wrong with it? The compiled LuceneServlet.class is located in /WEB-INF/classes/com/utm/csc/server/, is that web.xml correct?

Thanks

Comment: My first idea is to change <url-pattern>/LuceneServlet</url-pattern> to <url-pattern>/SearchTest/LuceneServlet</url-pattern>.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is not with the servlet mapping as you would have seen more errors in the logs if the servlet was not available at time of loading. The likely problem is that the url path of the servlet and that path that you are trying to post to are different. Would you mind putting the relevant excerpt of your GWT code

Comment: To exclude one and other, what's the full URL of the servlet as you would type in browser's address bar in order to invoke its `doGet()`? Big chance you actually needed a context path and this was missing in the HTML form action.

Comment: Heh, it was a relative thing. On the GWT debug server it was being deployed to the web server root, on tomcat it was deployed to a subdirectory. Deploying to root fixed all it.